# Magento 2.2.2 Add a custom tab on product page

Tags: magento2.2, tabs, product-page

I want to **add** a **custom tab** on **product page**, just like **(Details, More Information, Reviews)** .

What is the approach to implement this task.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your theme **Magento_Catalog >> Layout >> catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
     <block class="<vendor>\<module>\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="custom_product_tab" template="<Vendor>_<ModuleName>::product/tabs/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
         <arguments>
             <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom</argument>
         </arguments>
     </block>           
</referenceBlock>
```

> > If you want to add static content you can add `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` class in Block instead of custom class

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[First Refer this Link](https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-product-page-layout/)

> app/code/Ravindra/HelloWorld/View/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="demo.tab" template="Ravindra_HelloWorld::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Cutom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Ravindra/HelloWorld/View/frontend/templates/custom_tab.phtml

```
<?php // Get current product
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>

<h1 style="color: #ff5501"><?php echo $product->getData('demo'); ?></h1>
```